# When you clear "Cookies and other site data" in Chrome, are you clearing Chrome's DNS cache too?

Tags: google-chrome, dns

I know you can clear Chrome's DNS cache in chrome://net-internals/#dns.  But I suspect the DNS cache will also be cleared (along with Cookies, etc) by clearing "Cookies and other site data" in Chrome settings.  Is this the case?

Any clarification much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DNS cache is entirely different from site data, and certainly
different than cookies.
The DNS entry of a site isn't attached to the site data.

This is similar to the answer for your own
Google Support post :
[When you clear "Cookies and other site data" in Chrome, are you clearing Chrome's DNS cache too?](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/216844177/when-you-clear-cookies-and-other-site-data-in-chrome-are-you-clearing-chrome-s-dns-cache-too?hl=en)